# PHP contact form returning sent but it isn't sending

Tags: php, forms, contacts

I have tried to make sure others mistakes aren't here but I can't seem to fix this problem. When I run a test by entering a Name, email and message it returns the thanks for the message but never sends the email.

Hopefully this one isn't a stupid typo

HTML:

```
            <form method="post" action="contact.php" id="contactform">

                <div>
                <p>Send us your message</p>
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Username <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Email <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="" />
                </div>

                <div>
                <label>Message <span class="required">*</span></label>
                <textarea name="message" rows="20" cols="50"  id="message" ></textarea><br /><br />
                </div>

                <div>
                <input type="submit"  value="Submit" class="button">
                <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="button">
                </div>

            </form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$field_name    = $_POST['name'];
$field_email   = $_POST['email'];
$field_message = $_POST['message'];

$mail_to = 'test@email.com';
$subject = 'Web message from '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Thank you for the message.');
    window.location = '/';
  </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    alert('Message failed.);
    window.location = '/';
  </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: Documentation has this to say "It is important to note that just because the mail was accepted for delivery, it does NOT mean the mail will actually reach the intended destination." http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php best thing is to make use of SMTP or an API

Comment: I assume you changed the $mail_to variable to test@email.com just for this post and that is not the problem?

Answer (score -2):

please dont do things like that. You need to escape and clean the user input with something like [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) and you can simply use

```
header('Location: http://example.org/');
exit();
```

For your question: In my opinion the mail function is not good to use in any given situation. Simply because there are many webhosting services that don't allow using it or with a limit. I´d use something like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), which uses smtp for sending and retrieving email data. Keep in mind, that you need an email account for using libraries like that.

Manni

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I will switch to something like that instead.

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string?!? OP is not putting anything in a database

Comment: You should always escape user data no matter what you are doing with them. mysql_real_esape_string was just an example what op can use.